# Jquery- built-in confirm dialog

Tags: jquery

The following code is working correctly on localhost, but not on the server.  I think 'confirm' is a kind of plugin function.

```
var ask = confirm('Are you sure');
if (ask){
    $('.loading_gif').show();
    $('.delete_link').hide();
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
```

I want to use some built-in function to do same thing. How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: "but not on the server" What is not working correctly? Doesn't the confirm-dialog pop up? Is there a wrong value in `ask`?

Comment: IE had the behaviour of blocking dialogs in remote sites, didn't it? I'd check for similar plugins installed in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`confirm` is a javascript method to provide a prompt with an ok, or cancel button (browser dependent i think). the `if(ask)` statement checks to see if `ask = true`, when the `cancel prompt's ok button` is clicked, it returns `true` to the function, `if cancel button is clickd`, false returns. This is not a problem with the scope of this function.

Comment: [`window.confirm()` @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.confirm)

Answer (score 1):

`confirm` should be standard JavaScript library function.

if it's not working on the server, check the following

- check if jQuery script is included/loaded on the page
- check if there are any error logged in console
- try different browser, as JavaScript is client-side script, it has nothing to do with the server.